# Wrap all of your class in try/catch javascript?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

How to implement a class with method like following?

```
class ExistingClass {
     function func1() {} // might throw error
     function func2() {} // might throw error
     get try() {
        // Some magic here
        return this; // we need to return this to chain the calls, right? 
     }
}
```

and can be called like

```
obj.func1() //might throw an error
obj.try.func1() // execute func1 in a try/catch
```

basically i would want something like what mochajs has: `expect(..).to.not.equal()`

UPDATE:
The accepted answer should work, the following is a updated version of it with support for `async` function

```
get try() {
    return new Proxy(this, {

        // Intercept method getter
        get: function(target, name) {
            if (typeof target[name] === 'function') {
                if (target[name][Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction') {
                    return async function() {
                        try {
                           await target[name].apply(target, arguments);
                        }
                        catch (e) {}
                    }
                } else {
                    return function() {
                        try {
                            return target[name].apply(target, arguments)
                        }
                        catch (e) {}
                    }
                }
            }
            return target[name];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you need to be able to call the functions like that `obj.try.func1()` ? Can you use something like this: `obj.try("func1")` ?

Comment: `get try {` ... really? that works?

Comment: My two cents: If I ever see code or comments along the lines of "swallow error", I run the other way. Just sayin'.

Comment: You should correct errors, not *swallow* them.

Comment: i see that mochajs they have something like. `expect(val).not.equal()`. I would do something like that. it make code much nicer to read. And of course, we shouldn't swallow the error, there is a case that we just want to "try" and the `error` would not be matter that much. Anyway, i just want to know if it's possible to do something like this. I never say that it's a good code though.

Comment: I just want to point out it is bad idea to swallow error but it is a very good learning exercise to try to implement a solution.

Comment: @BryanChen exactly what i post this question for.

Comment: People are overreacting. This is an API that lets you choose to swallow errors (or provide some default behavior) when it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An simplified version of [elclanrs's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696769/642626)

```
class A {
  method() {
    throw 'Error';
  }

  get try() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      // Intercept method getter
      get(target, name) {
        if (typeof target[name] === 'function') {
          return function () {
              try {
                  return target[name].apply(target, arguments)
              } catch (e) {}
          }
        }
        return target[name];
      }
    });
  }
}

const a = new A;

a.try.method(); // no error

a.method(); // throws error
```

Comment: This by far is the nicest solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with proxies in the latest browsers:

```
class A {
  method() {
    throw 'Error';
  }

  get try() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      // Intercept method getter
      get(target, name) {
        if (typeof target[name] === 'function') {
          return new Proxy(target[name], {
            // Intercept method call
            apply(target, self, args) {
              try {
                return target.apply(self, args);
              } catch(e) {
                // swallow error
              }
            }
          })
        }
        return target[name];
      }
    });
  }
}

const a = new A;

a.try.method(); // no error

a.method(); // throws error
```

Comment: No need to double proxy. The proxied getter could just return a function that calls the original function in try catch.

Comment: @BryanChen i really want to see your solution for this?

Comment: @BryanChen, sure, that's a possible solution as well and proxy is probably worse for performance anyway.

Comment: There is one catch in the solution provided by @SkinnyPete is that if we refer to `this` in the method, it will be `undefined` after `try`. @elclanrs's answer actually keep the `this` reference intact

Comment: @jAckOdE: Ah yes, I shouldn't have used `apply()` int he first place. [`return targ[prop](...args)`](https://jsfiddle.net/3xm70t4k/2/)

Answer (score 4):

For `pre-ES6` browsers, that have no support `Proxies`, here is how I would do it, if I ever needed a feature like that:

```js
/* A constructor created the old-fashioned way. */
function ExistingClass () {
  /* The object that will be assigned to this.try. */
  var shadowObj = {};
  
  /* The function that throws an error (calls illegal constructor). */
  this.func1 = function () {
    return new Element();
  };
  
  /* Iterate over every property of the context. */
  for (var func in this) {
    /* Check whether the property is a function. */
    if (this[func] && this[func].constructor == Function) {
      /* Create a shadow function of the context's method. */
      shadowObj[func] = function () {
        try { return this[func]() }
        catch (e) { console.log("Error caught: " + e.message) }
      }.bind(this);
    }
  }
  
  /* Assign the shadow object to this.try. */
  this.try = shadowObj;
}

/* Example. */
var cls = new ExistingClass;
cls.try.func1();
cls.func1();
```

Comment: interesting to see another approach here.